# Unable to send GET request from Cloud application

Tags: java, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a java web application running on local Cloud_Foundry(bosh-lite) hosted on the Virtual box. The application is not able to send the http GET request to the servlet application running on the VMWare. As I able to ping from the one VM to the other VM.
Logs as follow:

```
    2017-03-17T18:49:03.75-0400 [RTR/0]      OUT sampleapp.bosh-lite.com - [2017-03-17T22:49:02.752+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" "10.244.0.34:48796" "10.244.16.9:61002" x_forwarded_for:"192.168.50.1, 10.244.0.34" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:"e3bd0592-eb4d-4d54-462c-6319d3346ad7" response_time:1.006039512 app_id:"98a99580-1082-4f4f-aa70-9b2952aef639" app_index:"0"
2017-03-17T18:49:03.75-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT [CONTAINER] ontainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[Servlet1] SEVERE  Servlet.service() for servlet [Servlet1] in context with path [] threw exception
```

Is it a case cloudfoundry container not able to access the IP outside the VM on which it is deployed. If this is the case what can I it enable. Someone please help

Thanks,

Comment: Really hard to say, you need to provide more info.  First suggestion would be to run `cf ssh` and enter the container for your app.  From there, perform basic network troubleshooting like `ping`, `nc` and `curl` to test connectivity to your external resource.  Also, look at your security groups.  These affect out going traffic from the containers.  I don't know what the default is on CF deployed via Bosh Lite, but they could be blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a bit more information to troubleshoot your application exception and remote debug per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-tips.html#debugging could help with that.

Other helpful debug commands:

```
export CF_TRACE=true
cf events YOURAPPNAME
cf logs YOURAPPNAME
```